# IF OR / DATEIF calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula

I have a calculated column that returns days open for job listings.

```
=DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")-IF(WEEKDAY(TodayDate)=7,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")+WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date]))/7,1)*2,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")+WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date]))/7,1)*2)+IF(WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date])=7,2,1)
```

This is great and works well but doesn't take into account if a Candidate starts so it continues to count.

I created another column and used this formula:
`=IF(ISBLANK([Candidate Start Date]),"",[Candidate Start Date]-[Requisition Open Date]+1)` which only adds the day a requisition took to fill.

My question. Is it possible to use an if/or statement on this?
I created a hybrid but only get a #Value! in the column:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Candidate Start Date]),"",[Candidate Start Date]-[Requisition Open Date]+1),DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")-IF(WEEKDAY(TodayDate)=7,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")+WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date]))/7,1)*2,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")+WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date]))/7,1)*2)+IF(WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date])=7,2,1))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I have understood you correctly, but do you want to stop counting the days if `Candidate Start Date` has a value?
If so, try this one instead:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Candidate Start Date]),DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")-IF(WEEKDAY(TodayDate)=7,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")+WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date]))/7,1)*2,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")+WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date]))/7,1)*2)+IF(WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date])=7,2,1),[Candidate Start Date]-[Requisition Open Date]+1)
```

*Note:*

If `A` = `DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")-IF(WEEKDAY(TodayDate)=7,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")+WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date]))/7,1)*2,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Requisition Open Date],TodayDate,"D")+WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date]))/7,1)*2)+IF(WEEKDAY([Requisition Open Date])=7,2,1)`

Then the formula is

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Candidate Start Date]),A,[Candidate Start Date]-[Requisition Open Date]+1)
```

Comment: Chelsea_MSFT  thanks very much. Stop counting the days is exactly what I was going for. Just plugged the formula in and it worked like a charm. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @msm02eshift Please, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!